# Jackson-Databind ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException Version 2.6.0

Tags: json, jackson

i have updated to jackson-databind 2.6.0 to fix a deserialization bug. But, now i receive a new one (i checked the same test with Version 2.4.0 and 2.5.4, both worked).

Here is the exception:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 56
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.BeanPropertyMap.withProperty(BeanPropertyMap.java:177)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBuilder.build(BeanDeserializerBuilder.java:344)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.buildBeanDeserializer(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:251)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.createBeanDeserializer(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:142)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer2(DeserializerCache.java:403)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:352)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:264)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:244)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.findValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:142)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findRootValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:461)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._findRootDeserializer(ObjectMapper.java:3804)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3698)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2714)
    at com.mleitner.businessmaximizer.webservice.JacksonMapperTest.testOneTimeCustomer(JacksonMapperTest.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
```

The test is simple:

```
@Test
    public void testOneTimeCustomer() throws Exception {
        OneTimeCustomerDTO customer = new OneTimeCustomerDTO("Max", null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
        ObjectMapper om = new MyObjectMapper();
        String result = om.writeValueAsString(customer);
        System.out.println("Result:" + result);
        om.readValue(result, OneTimeCustomerDTO.class);
    }

and has this output: Result:{"@id":1,"firstName":"Max"}
```

The class MyObjectMapper does some config which i always use. The config is set to:

```
this.setVisibility(
                getSerializationConfig().
                getDefaultVisibilityChecker().
                withFieldVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY).
                withGetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE).
                withSetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE).
                withCreatorVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE).
                withIsGetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE));
        this.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
        this.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        this.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_NULL_MAP_VALUES, false);

        this.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
```

And i have an AnnotationIntrospector which adds ids for recursive structures:

```
@Override
    public ObjectIdInfo findObjectIdInfo(final Annotated ann) {
        if (BaseDTO.class.isAssignableFrom(ann.getRawType())) {
            // this is needed for recursive structures
            return new ObjectIdInfo(PropertyName.construct("@id", null),
                    ann.getRawType(),
                    ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, null);
        }
        return super.findObjectIdInfo(ann);
    }
```

My DTO looks like this:
OneTimeCustomerDTO->CustomerDTO(abstract)->BaseDTO(abstract).

OneTimeCustomerDTO has 8 String attributes, CustomerDTO 1 String and 1 long attribute. Both have also complex attributes (other classes), but they are null during this test so i think they are not relevant.

If i remove the ObjectIdInfo it also works with 2.6.0... but i need this to transfer recursive structures.

So my questions are:

- Any idea for an workaround?
- I didn't find a possibility to report a
  bug to jackson-databind?! Because i believe this is a bug and all
  should work fine...

Thanks in advance for your time and efforts.

kr

Comment: Looks like it is now reported as https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/884 and hopefully will be resolved for 2.6.1.

Comment: Yeah, i reported it and it's fixed by version 2.6.1 => retest was successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use version 2.6.1. It is a bug in 2.6.0